# Deploying app to Heroku throwing a 500 Internal Server Error in Back End Java Spring Boot while works perfect on local enviroment

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vue.js, heroku

Good Day developers.In this app i'm building im having a little issue with a rating process i want to implement. Being the app working on local host is perfect but once i posted in Heroku , its error log throws me this error on 500 Internal Error.

I just posted this videos in order you could see either cases i try to apply:

1rst case (Either passing object or integer to request body parameter  with app working in local , perfect performance)
https://youtu.be/IdpHQg4FW7k

2nd case(Passing integer to request body parameter with app in heroku, error 500)
https://youtu.be/eJHSA_h8R3Y

3rd case(Passing object to request body parameter with  app in heroku ,error 500)
https://youtu.be/_l-Z0I3hNZU

Guess with this videos i expose more on detail what's going on, notwithstanding , i'm going to leave the code below before this current edit.Thanks for your support

Basically from my front end i just send through a request body parameter a rate(selected by user among 1-5 integer-numbers) :

```
COMPONENT in VUE
        functionx(){
         this.$store.dispatch("rateUpdater", {
            ratePack: {
              productRate: 4,
            },
            product_id: this.ProductCard.product_id,

          });
        }

VUEX Process

     rateUpdater({ dispatch }, { product_id, ratePack }) {
        fetch(url+"mini/all_products/user/product_rated/" + product_id, {
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(ratePack),
      })
        .then((newData) => {
          return newData.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.Error) {
            data.Error
          } else {
            data;
            dispatch("fetchAllProducts");
          }
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          alert("Request on Rate: ", error);
        });
    },
```

Thus then  receiving that data in my back end , i just initially get initialized that variable on my request body as Integer , cause is the way it comes from front-end, then basically i change it to a Double believing that could work :

```
CONTROLLER

importations

package com.miniAmazon;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@RequestMapping(value="/mini/all_products/user/product_rated/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity <Map<String,Object>>rateProductOnBuy(@PathVariable("id") Long id,  Authentication authentication
                                                                ,@RequestBody Integer productRated
    ){
        SOME CODE.....

        Product product=productRepository.getOne(id);

        Double rate=new Double(productRated)----------->transforming integer of request body to double 


        ---------------process of calculating average rate--------------------
        Double deframingRate=product.getProductRate()*product.getPeopleRating()+rate;
        Integer deframingPeopleVoting=product.getPeopleRating()+1;
        Double finalAverage=deframingRate/deframingPeopleVoting;

       -----------setting new Rate-------------
        product.setProductRate(finalAverage);

        ---------setting new amount of voters-----------
        product.setPeopleRating(deframingPeopleVoting);

        ---------saving repository----
        productRepository.save(product);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(makeMapResponse("Success","Product Rated"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

but Basically that little change didn't work .....Any idea about how could i deal with this problem ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you write `@RequestBody Integer productRated` that means that the accepted request body is just one single number. It cannot be an object containing a key-value pair for the number.

You may be able to fix this by changing the client so it only sends a number, not an object:

```
 rateUpdater({ dispatch }, { product_id, ratePack }) {
    fetch(url+"mini/all_products/user/product_rated/" + product_id, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: ratePack.productRate, // just a number!
  })
```

This is not very extensible though, because you can't send more than this one number in the body.

To make this extensible, you can for example create a class that represents the request body:

```
class YourRequestType {
    Integer productRate; // add getters, setters, if you want
}
```

and use that class in your controller method declaration.

```
@RequestBody YourRequestType productRated
```

Comment: it throws me a 500 error and looking on Heroku log there isn't too much i could find for

Comment: And is confusing , cause working on local all works perfectly....

Comment: What is the js data type of the `ratePack` in `JSON.stringify(ratePack)`? According to your logs, Jackson is complaining that you are trying to pass a js object (START_OBJECT) but you are expecting only a `Integer` in the `@RequestBody`. Are you sure your local data matches what would be used deployed in Heroku? The 500 may be a bug in your controller code with the new request body object @Joni suggested.